# EOFException in Java using JPBC library for ABE

Tags: java, cryptography, eofexception

I am trying to run an example of Attribute-Based Encryption using the JPBC library found here using eclipse: [JPBC ABE](http://gas.dia.unisa.it/projects/jpbc/schemes/abe_gghvv13.html#.WNzjg_krKUm). When i run the code i get the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.EOFException
    at it.unisa.dia.gas.plaf.jpbc.util.io.PairingStreamReader.readString(PairingStreamReader.java:93)
    at it.unisa.dia.gas.crypto.jpbc.fe.abe.gghvv13.engines.GGHVV13KEMEngine.process(GGHVV13KEMEngine.java:45)
    at it.unisa.dia.gas.crypto.jpbc.cipher.PairingAsymmetricBlockCipher.processBlock(PairingAsymmetricBlockCipher.java:88)
    at it.unisa.dia.gas.crypto.jpbc.kem.PairingKeyEncapsulationMechanism.processBlock(PairingKeyEncapsulationMechanism.java:37)
    at com.crypto.GGHVV13KEM.decaps(GGHVV13KEM.java:83)
    at com.crypto.GGHVV13KEM.main(GGHVV13KEM.java:124)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readUnsignedShort(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(Unknown Source)
    at it.unisa.dia.gas.plaf.jpbc.util.io.PairingStreamReader.readString(PairingStreamReader.java:91)
    ... 5 more
```

I have included all the necessary libraries. How can i go about fixing this?

Code:

```
import it.unisa.dia.gas.crypto.circuit.Circuit;
import it.unisa.dia.gas.crypto.circuit.DefaultCircuit;
import it.unisa.dia.gas.crypto.jpbc.fe.abe.gghvv13.engines.GGHVV13KEMEngine;
import it.unisa.dia.gas.crypto.jpbc.fe.abe.gghvv13.generators.GGHVV13KeyPairGenerator;
import it.unisa.dia.gas.crypto.jpbc.fe.abe.gghvv13.generators.GGHVV13ParametersGenerator;
import it.unisa.dia.gas.crypto.jpbc.fe.abe.gghvv13.generators.GGHVV13SecretKeyGenerator;
import it.unisa.dia.gas.crypto.jpbc.fe.abe.gghvv13.params.*;
import it.unisa.dia.gas.crypto.kem.KeyEncapsulationMechanism;
import it.unisa.dia.gas.plaf.jpbc.pairing.PairingFactory;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.AsymmetricCipherKeyPair;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.CipherParameters;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.InvalidCipherTextException;

import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.util.Arrays;

import static it.unisa.dia.gas.crypto.circuit.Circuit.Gate.Type.*;
import static it.unisa.dia.gas.crypto.circuit.DefaultCircuit.DefaultGate;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

/**
* @author Angelo De Caro (jpbclib@gmail.com)
*/
public class GGHVV13KEM {

   public GGHVV13KEM() {
   }


   public AsymmetricCipherKeyPair setup(int n) {
       GGHVV13KeyPairGenerator setup = new GGHVV13KeyPairGenerator();
       setup.init(new GGHVV13KeyPairGenerationParameters(
               new SecureRandom(),
               new GGHVV13ParametersGenerator().init(
                       PairingFactory.getPairing("D:/mrstar/Documents/Java Libs/2.0/params/mm/ctl13/toy.properties"),
                       n).generateParameters()
       ));

       return setup.generateKeyPair();
   }

   public byte[][] encaps(CipherParameters publicKey, String w) {
       try {
           KeyEncapsulationMechanism kem = new GGHVV13KEMEngine();
           kem.init(true, new GGHVV13EncryptionParameters((GGHVV13PublicKeyParameters) publicKey, w));

           byte[] ciphertext = kem.process();

           assertNotNull(ciphertext);
           assertNotSame(0, ciphertext.length);

           byte[] key = Arrays.copyOfRange(ciphertext, 0, kem.getKeyBlockSize());
           byte[] ct = Arrays.copyOfRange(ciphertext, kem.getKeyBlockSize(), ciphertext.length);

           return new byte[][]{key, ct};
       } catch (InvalidCipherTextException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
           fail(e.getMessage());
       }
       return null;
   }

   public CipherParameters keyGen(CipherParameters publicKey, CipherParameters masterSecretKey, Circuit circuit) {
       GGHVV13SecretKeyGenerator keyGen = new GGHVV13SecretKeyGenerator();
       keyGen.init(new GGHVV13SecretKeyGenerationParameters(
               (GGHVV13PublicKeyParameters) publicKey,
               (GGHVV13MasterSecretKeyParameters) masterSecretKey,
               circuit
       ));

       return keyGen.generateKey();
   }

   public byte[] decaps(CipherParameters secretKey, byte[] ciphertext) {
       try {
           KeyEncapsulationMechanism kem = new GGHVV13KEMEngine();

           kem.init(false, secretKey);
           byte[] key = kem.processBlock(ciphertext);

           assertNotNull(key);
           assertNotSame(0, key.length);

           return key;
       } catch (InvalidCipherTextException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
           fail(e.getMessage());
       }

       return null;
   }


   public static void main(String[] args) {
       int n = 4;
       int q = 3;
       Circuit circuit = new DefaultCircuit(n, q, 3, new DefaultGate[]{
              new DefaultGate(INPUT, 0, 1),
              new DefaultGate(INPUT, 1, 1),
              new DefaultGate(INPUT, 2, 1),
              new DefaultGate(INPUT, 3, 1),

              new DefaultGate(AND, 4, 2, new int[]{0, 1}),
              new DefaultGate(OR, 5, 2, new int[]{2, 3}),

              new DefaultGate(AND, 6, 3, new int[]{4, 5}),
      });

      GGHVV13KEM kem = new GGHVV13KEM();

      // Setup
      AsymmetricCipherKeyPair keyPair = kem.setup(n);

      // Keygen
      CipherParameters secretKey = kem.keyGen(keyPair.getPublic(), keyPair.getPrivate(), circuit);

      // Encaps/Decaps for satisfying assignment
      String assignment = "1101";
      byte[][] ct = kem.encaps(keyPair.getPublic(), assignment);
      assertEquals(true, Arrays.equals(ct[0], kem.decaps(secretKey, ct[1])));

      // Encaps/Decaps for not-satisfying assignment
      assignment = "1001";
      ct = kem.encaps(keyPair.getPublic(), assignment);
      assertEquals(false, Arrays.equals(ct[0], kem.decaps(secretKey, ct[1])));
  }

}
```

Comment: This looks like a bug in the example code and should be sent to Angelo de Caro, but last time I added an issue, he didn't respond. The bug depends on the underlying engine (`GGHVV13KEMEngine`). So, I don't think a Stack Overflow question is the right way to tackle this. Have a look at [Arcanum](https://github.com/adecaro/arcanum). Maybe it is fixed there.

Comment: Have you solved this problem?